# Finding out what values didn't merge in R

Tags: r

If I had two simple dataframes:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
df1 <-data.frame(a,b)

c <- 1:7
d <- c("k","l","m","n","o","p","q")
df2 <-data.frame(c,d)
```

... and I wanted to merge them by "a" and "c" for df1 and df2 respectively using:

```
df3= merge(df1, df2, by.x = "a", by.y = "c")
```

How would I go about producing a dataframe of rows in df1 which didn't merge?  For example:

```
    a b
8   8 h
9   9 i
10 10 j
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

EDIT
Using the suggestion in the comment, I can do:

```
check = setdiff(df1$a, df2$c)
```

This is great, as I get 8:10 which is correct, but I do need the other column in df1 listed to...  Can this be done with setdiff too?

Comment: Maybe `setdiff` on `df3$a` vs. `df1$a` ?

Comment: setdiff looks interesting @Carl Witthoft - can I use it to find out the other columns numbers as well?

Comment: `df1[1:dim(df1)[1]  %in% check,]`

Comment: @Codoremifa nice construction there.  I'll post `setdiff` as an answer & give you credit.

Answer (score 3):

Look up the `all` argument.

```
df3= merge(df1, df2, by.x = "a", by.y = "c", all.x = TRUE)
```

will return this. Now you can filter on d to get the entries you're looking for.

```
    a b    d
1   1 a    k
2   2 b    l
3   3 c    m
4   4 d    n
5   5 e    o
6   6 f    p
7   7 g    q
8   8 h <NA>
9   9 i <NA>
10 10 j <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per comments:

```
check = setdiff(df1$a, df2$c)

alldiff <- df1[1:dim(df1)[1] %in% check,]
```

(note that `dim(df1)[1]` is the same as, say, `length(df1$a)` )

With credit to Codoremifa for the second line.